# How to add a directory to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable?

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu

Im new using Ubuntu, the problem is that i want to install opencv, then i want to see the version of the installed program using this sentence

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

Then the terminal shows me this type of "error"

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

I tried to do everything and it doesnt work, someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the development package as:

```
apt install libopencv-dev
```

Comment: Sorry if i answer late, but when i want to install de development package it shows me this

`E: The lock file could not be opened "/ var / lib / dpkg / lock" - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not block the administration directory (/ var / lib / dpkg /), is it as superuser?`

Comment: Ok... now i fixed it, the problem was that i didnt use "root" user, now i could install the `libopencv-dev` thanks!

Comment: I tried this and it said I already had it installed. So I removed and then installed it again. The apt --reinstall flag did not work.